# Why do I get another result?

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

I tried to solve this project for school and when i use a compiler the final  result is some emoticons instead of the sum of digits

I rewrote the entire code, but I get the same result

```
.model small  
.stack 100h  
.data 
nstr db 6 dup(' ') 
idv dw 10 
a dw 2  
b dw 9  
c dw 6 
x dw ?  ;x=a+b+c
d dw 7 
e dw 5 
y dw ?  ;y=d+e
z dw ?  ;z=x+y
.code 
.start 
mov ds, ax  
; x = a+b+c 
mov ax, a 
add ax, b 
add ax, c  
mov x, ax 
; y = d+e

mov ax, d 
add ax, e 
mov y, ax 
; z = x+y

mov ax, x 
add ax, y 
mov z , ax 
mov si,5  
mov nstr[si], '$' 
dec si 


mov ax, z 
mov dx,0

loop1: ; 
div idv  

;
add dl, '0'  
mov nstr[si],dl 

dec si 

mov dx,0 


cmp ax,0 
jne loop1  

listn:  
mov ah, 09h 
mov dx, offset nstr ;
int 21h 

stopprg:  
mov ah, 4ch 
int 21h 

end
```

Comment: Thank you very much. that was the problem

Comment: @MichaelPetch If that was the answer, please write it down as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

The `.start` directive will produce code that will initialize the segments for the model you have chosen (in this case `small`). You overwrite *DS* with whatever happens to be in *AX* with `mov ds, ax`. That will point the data segment to a place in memory that doesn't contain your data (like `nstr`, `idv`, `a` ... `z` etc) producing incorrect results.  To fix simply remove this line:

```
mov ds, ax
```